# CSS table-cell widths work in Chrome but not FF or IE

Tags: css, css-tables

Using display:table-cell, I've found, is a useful way to get things to center vertically--especially in a RWD context where static px dimensions won't work. I'm trying to get a logo img and some text to center vertically to each other without using floats.

See here: 
http://dabblet.com/gist/5249192 .

In Chrome, it works as expected. When the browser gets sized smaller, the img gets smaller and the text wraps and stuff. But in FF, IE 9, and Opera, the image won't shrink, in fact it seems all width and height declarations are ignored.

Is there some change I can make to my current HTML/CSS to fix that or is the fact that Chrome is supporting my current layout a happy mistake and I'm going about this all wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I just figured it out.

Max-width only applies to block level elements so the img {max-width:100%;} declaration doesn't work, which prevents the image from having a fluid width. Cleared that issue up by targeting the img and giving it a width:100%; Boom!

Answer (score 0):

`display:table-cell` isn't really intended to to be used without a corresponding `display:table-row` and `display:table` in the parent elements.

You don't have that, and you're clearly not trying to use it as a table cell. Although you may have had some success with using it to center content, that isn't what it's designed for,  so it's not really a surprise that it doesn't work in all browsers.

If you really want to use `table-cell` for this and it's not doing what you want it to, maybe you could try adding adding `table-row` and `table` styles to the parent elements (you may need additional markup for this, as they'll have an effect on the existing styles if you put them on `wrapper` and `header`).

Comment: I like semantics and using things as they're intended, but there doesn't seem to be another way to get elements to center vertically relative to each other without setting heights or negative margins. Do you know of a way to achieve vertical alignment while avoiding all the mess I described above and being semantically correct?

Comment: I'm not necessarily saying 'don't use `table-cell`' (the CSS isn't really relevant to semantics, so that's not the issue). What I'm saying is that it'll probably work better if you use it in conjunction with a `table-row` and `table`, because that's how it's designed to work.